Market Data UST
There a lot of new market data providers for retail algo traders.
For example the famous one for option is Theta Data Net and for Equities it is Polygon IO. You basically get all the greek/price data for ~60$/month.
I was wondering if the same exists for US treasuries? So a data providers that gives tick data information for UST at an affordable price for retail traders.
